# Please connect this device to Xcode to install the development support files

Tags: iphone, xcode, xamarin.ios

I'm developing an iPhone application with Monotouch. 
My app' works well for now, and I want to test more.

But, suddenly, I've got this error I've never seen before. 
Google couldn't help me, I hope you can.

```
error MT0000: Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com
System.Exception: Could not find developer tools for this device. Please connect this device to Xcode to install the development support files.
  at MonoTouch.Installation.Device.MountDeveloperImage () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Installation.Installer.KillApplication (MonoTouch.Installation.Device d, System.String appId) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoTouch.Installation.Installer+<KillApplication>c__AnonStorey7.<>m__8 (MonoTouch.Installation.Device d) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I found this issue on Pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/9anpZgzd). That's all.

Last week, everything was okay.
I cleaned my project, built and rebuilt it, rebooted the system, opened XCode, opened the Views with XCode (to load the Xcode project), nothing works.
And now, none of apps run correctly.

Maybe this is caused by a XCode update ?
Or is this caused by the iOS update (6.0.1) ?

**Edit:** I've also contacted the Xamarin Support Center. I'll keep in touch.

**Edit 2:** Here is the answer from Xamarin Support

> This is an issue we are aware of and have fixed this in MonoTouch
>   6.0.6 (which is currently in the beta channel). If you don't want to update to MonoTouch 6.0.6, there's a workaround posted on the bug here
>   https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=8166 that you can apply
>   to resolve the issue.
>
> I hope this helps.

I valid MJJames answer for pointing the problem at first. 
Thanks a lot.

I try the fix and feed back.

**Edit 3:**
I changed the Update Channel (*MonoDevelop > Check for Updates*) to **Beta**, and downloaded the MonoTouch and MonoDevelop beta updates. And it works again. Xamarin, MJJames, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Xamarin have release MonoTouch 6.0.6 on to the Beta update channel, if you are fine to run the beta this fixes the issue.

http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/releases/MonoTouch_6/MonoTouch_6.0#MonoTouch_6.0.6

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use a beta version of XCode, you'll probably need to point Xamarin Studio to it manually.  At least if you're using Xamarin Studio 5.9 or later.

From https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18658/xcode-6-beta:

> Hi,
>
> Yes, just change the Apple SDK location in Xamarin Studio Preferences
>   -> Projects -> SDK Locations -> Apple settings page. Click the Browse button and navigate to the XCode6-Beta5.app in the Applications
>   folder.

Replace the XCode6-Beta5-app location with something more modern:

[image]

And then if you get an a error mentioning DetectSdkLocations, [you may need to reboot](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/40392/the-detectsdklocations-task-failed-unexpectedly).